# How to debug an Asp.Net Mvc Application in Visual Studio 2012 from a remote computer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have two computers connected and I have made `Remote Desktop Connection` from `Computer A` to `Computer B`.

I opened `Visual Studio 2012` in `Computer B` , and started debugging Asp.Net MVC Application , it works correctly in browser of local machine and it is also hosted on `IIS`. But when I open that MVC Application from `Computer A's` browser , than debuging does not work , i.e. no breakpoints are hit.

I have searched about it , and came across `Remote Debugging Monitor` , but I am not able to use it.

I need help in this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**If your remote machine is also the IIS server:**

If you share your Remote Debugger Folder out so it can be accessed on the remote machine. Folder for 2012 should be

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger

On the remote machine access the folder and run the `msvsmon.exe`
It will give you a server name once launched. Then on your local machine, in VS2012, in the debug menu, select attach to process.

Enter the server name provided by the remote debugger into the Qualifier field and attach to the `w3wp.exe` process

**if your IIS server is the localhost and your remote machine connects to it:**

You dont need remote debugger, just attach to process from the debug menu and select the `w3wp.exe` process.

For good measure, [here is the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx)