# Debuging System.NullReferenceException happening on server

Tags: c#, debugging, exception

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. One of the methods is throwing System.NullReferenceException "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Unfortunately, it happens only on server, local version of code is working perfectly fine. How can I debug it to know which object is causing an issue, or at least on which line number does the code processing brake?

Comment: If you're on Azure, you can debug remotely

Comment: It should be possible, if this code is not going live currently, to put a try catch over the whole thing and on the catch take a parameter `(Exception e)` which is to be output in a message box like `MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());`

Hope this helps

Comment: First, print your stack trace to show the specific method that is throwing an exception. Next, refactor that method by extracting it into smaller and smaller methods. Eventually, you'll find the culprit based on the stack trace. Sometimes methods are hard to debug merely because they're too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use a decent logging framework and `try...catch` blocks to get information on the approximate location of the problem. Print stack traces.

Then try to narrow down the issue:

- If possible, try to [attach a remote debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18585852/993547);
- Add `Trace.WriteLine` or `Debug.Assert` statements and check for incoming parameters to have a value in your expected range;
- [Enable tracing](http://knucklebones.blogspot.nl/2010/11/enable-tracing-in-aspnet-mvc.html) on your server to get logging directly accessible in ASP.NET.